# What is numpy method int0?

Tags: python, numpy, methods, int

I've seen `np.int0` used for converting bounding box floating point values to int in OpenCV problems.

What exactly is `np.int0`?

I've seen `np.uint8`, `np.int32`, etc. I can't seem to find `np.int0` in any online documentation. What kind of int does this cast arguments to?

Comment: @Prune: Well, there is no NumPy documentation for int0, as the questioner said.

Comment: @user2357112: I disagree.  A simple search for "numpy int0 function" brings up plenty of identifications, even though it's a [package constant or class](http://numpy.sourceforge.net/numdoc/HTML/numdoc.htm) rather than a function.

Comment: Also, typing `numpy.int0` into the Python command line identifies the item.

Comment: @Prune: Those docs are extremely out of date and no longer accurate for modern NumPy; for example, they describe `Int0` (capital - the term never appears in lowercase) as the *smallest* integer available.

Comment: There are no occurrences of `int0` in the current NumPy docs. Typing `numpy.int0` into the command line isn't enough either; doing that, you might think it's a fixed-size type. One answerer already made that mistake.

Comment: Right; my link is to outdated information.  Still, the first page of hits included several references to `int0` being a built-in integer type, and two identified it as equivalent to `intp`.

Comment: @Prune: I don't know what your search results look like, but I get 0 results for `"numpy int0 function"` with quotes, and without quotes, the only result that even has int0 anywhere on the page is [this page full of unexplained code samples scraped from people's repositories](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57103/numpy.int0).

Comment: It has a value in `np.sctypeDict['int0']`, which was set in the `numerictypes.py` file.

Comment: @Prune Exactly. I do not find anything in the Numpy documentation referring to `np.int0`.

@user2357112 There are examples of usage of `np.int0` online, but none in the documentation

Comment: I messed up on the `@` names above and accidentally hit enter before I finished.  (butter fingers)

@user2357112 Exactly. I do not find anything in the Numpy documentation referring to `np.int0`.


@Prune There are examples of usage of `np.int0` online, but none in the documentation, which is what confused me. But I didn't think to type it into the command line. Thank you for that! Could you send me the links you are finding referencing `int0` being equivalent to `intp`. I'd like to submit these to numpydoc as a pull request for updating the docs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`int0` is an [alias for `intp`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/95b435aa91c7259256b5c8a35c92c942f4eeb7d0/numpy/core/numerictypes.py#L372); this, in turn, is

> Integer used for indexing (same as C ssize_t; normally either `int32` or `int64`)

-- [Numpy docs: basic types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.types.html)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Why is this not mentioned in the documentation in `Data types` on `Scipy.org`? This would have been helpful to know.

Comment: Now that question I don't have an answer for. :)

Comment: @A.Hendry Probably because no-one thought of it, [yet](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/bugs.html). (Although [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc) might be a better place to report the issue; or submit a pull-request).

Comment: @jpaugh: numpydoc is the Sphinx extension NumPy uses for docstring preprocessing; problems in the NumPy documentation should be reported on the main NumPy issue tracker.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks! That's what I get for trying to "drive-by" a community.

Comment: @A.Hendry, it's likely that `int0` is a legacy value,  `numpy` is the result of the merger of several numeric packages (more than 10 yrs ago).  So a variety of duplicate names and functions were retained for backward compatibility.  This is an alias, and not needed for new code.  `opencv` is as old, so the original Python port could have used one of the `numpy` predecessors.

Comment: @A.Hendry; I'm only finding `int0` in some `opencv` `py_tutorials`, not actual code  There's no indication as to who wrote them, or where they were ported from.

Answer (score 11):

It's a mere alias to `int64`, try this from either Python 2 or Python 3:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.int0 is numpy.int64
True
```

Comment: I think this depends on system architecture and OS

Comment: and actually the method in the OP question is the "constructor", `np.int0(1.7)` gives the integral part of its argument. Found in 2020 edition of a book about OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some more information:

```
# get complete list of datatype names
>>> np.sctypeDict.keys()

# returns the default integer type (here `int64`)
>>> np.sctypeDict['int0']
<class 'numpy.int64'>

# verify
>>> arr = np.int0([1, 2, 3])
>>> arr.nbytes
24
```